# jquery ui autocomplete, rails3 and CanCan model access problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have various roles defined by CanCan in my rails application. I recently implemented jQuery  UI autocomplete and it works well.  The problem is that when I submit the form, the find_by_name that occurs in the model can find records that do not belong to the current_user.  I have the following in my view:

```
<strong><%= f.label :inventory_name, "Material" %></strong>
<%= f.text_field :inventory_name, :class => "inputbox" %><br>
```

And my jQuery looks like:

```
jQuery("input[id$=_inventory_name]").autocomplete({
  source: '/ajax/inventory',
  minLength: 2
});
```

Then I have an ajax controller that does the right thing:

```
def inventory
  inventory = Inventory.accessible_by(current_ability)
  if params[:term]
    like= "%".concat(params[:term].concat("%"))
    names = inventory.where("name LIKE ?", like)
  else
    names = inventory
  end

  list = names.map {|u| Hash[ :id => u.id, :label => u.name, :name => u.name]}
  render :json => list
end
```

But my model does not:

```
def inventory_name=(name)
  inventory = Inventory.find_by_name(name)
  if inventory
    self.inventory_id = inventory.id
  else
    errors[:inventory_name] << "Invalid name entered"
  end
end
def inventory_name
  Inventory.find(inventory_id).name if inventory_id
end
```

find_by_name will return the first match it finds regardless of who owns it.  Ideally I'd like to change:

```
inventory = Inventory.find_by_name(name)
```

to

```
inventory = Inventory.accessible_by(current_ability).find_by_name(name)
```

But that violates the principles of MVC not to mention the model has no access to current_ability, current_user or the like.  So my question is, how to I move this logic into my controller where I have access to these things? I can't seem to wrap my head around it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing both a before and after filter:

```
after_filter :save_new_project_inventory, :only => [:create]
before_filter :update_project_inventory, :only => [:create, :update]
```

...

```
private
def save_new_project_inventory
  # do this in an after filter so that
  # we will have a project.id
  @project_inventories.each { |key, value|
    value[:project_id] = @project.id
    ProjectInventory.create!(value)
  }
end

def update_project_inventory
  @project_inventories = {}
  params[:project][:project_inventories_attributes].each { |key, value|
    if value[:_destroy] != "false"
      project_inventory = ProjectInventory.find(value[:id])
      project_inventory.delete
    else
      if value[:id]
        project_inventory = ProjectInventory.find(value[:id])
        project_inventory.inventory_id = inventory_name(value[:inventory_name])
        project_inventory.save
      else
        if @project.nil?
          # can't save here because we need a project.id that we
          # won't have until after we save, so finish up in the
          # after filter
          @project_inventories[key] = {
            :inventory_id => inventory_name(value[:inventory_name])
          }
        else
          project_inventory = ProjectInventory.new
          project_inventory.inventory_id = inventory_name(value[:inventory_name])
          project_inventory.project_id = params[:id]
          project_inventory.save
        end
      end
    end
  }
  params[:project].delete(:project_inventories_attributes)
end

def inventory_name(name)
  inventories = Inventory.accessible_by(current_ability)
  inventory = inventories.find_by_name(name)
  if inventory
    inventory.id.to_s
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is make your create and update actions in your controller check  `Inventory.accessible_by(current_ability)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the exact same problem and was stumped until just now. I ended up with a much simpler solution for anyone else looking.

In my example the current_user creates a job, and that job needs a customer assigned to it (one also belonging to the current user). jQuery UI autocomplete is used to search customers, and of course I only want customers that belong to the current user to be assignable to the job being created, much the same as in the original question. My final solution was simply to add a hidden field for the user_id to the new job form, populated with the user_id when the new action is called.

```
JobsController
def new
  @job = current_user.jobs.new(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

This way in the model, we can grab the user_id with self.user_id (taking the value in the hidden field) and then use it as part of our search criteria for the lookup. I have assigned self.user_id to variable 'user' for readability.

```
JobModel
def customer_name=(fullname)
  user = self.user_id
  self.customer = Customer.find_by(fullname: fullname, user_id: user) 
end
```

Simple as that, now unless both the search term (in this case :fullname), and the user_id are a match in the Customer model, no result is returned and the user is required to try again, even if a record with the same fullname exists in the Customer model with a different user_id, it wont be returned.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Remember to add user_id to permitted params.